# DAX Measure (e.g., "Count Rows") based upon filtered measure value (e.g., "[Sales]>100")

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to write a DAX measure that calculates (e.g., "Count Rows"), but only when another measure value is evaluated (e.g., filtering "[Sales]>100"). So if-- in the context of the selected filters-- Sales is great than 100, then the measure is executed only for those rows.

The measure I have defined works in the context of lower smaller grain. But the totals do not sum correctly.

Any suggestions?

**DAX Measure**

```
License Usage = 
// Users with active viewership in 3 months
IF (
    NOT ( ISBLANK (
        CALCULATE (
            [Activity Date NEWEST],
            KEEPFILTERS ( DATESINPERIOD ( dimCalendar[Date], TODAY (), -90, DAY ) )
        )
    )), 1
)

Activity Date NEWEST = 
MAX('PBI Activity'[Date])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured something out that works.

**DAX**

```
License Usage =
// Users with active viewership in 3 months
CALCULATE (
    [Count Users],
    FILTER ( 'PBI Activity', 'PBI Activity'[Date] >= TODAY () - 90 )
)

Count Users = COUNTROWS('Users')
```

[image]

Also, I later came across this article which looks like it also does what I was hoping to do: Execute calculate expression over filtered rows based upon measure filter.

Reference: [Specifying multiple filter conditions in CALCULATE - SQLBI](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/specifying-multiple-filter-conditions-in-calculate/)

**DAX**

```
DEFINE
    MEASURE Sales[Big Sales Amount] =
        CALCULATE (
            [Sales Amount],
            KEEPFILTERS (
                FILTER (
                    ALL ( Sales[Quantity], Sales[Net Price] ),
                    Sales[Quantity] * Sales[Net Price] > 1000
                )
            )
        )
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Sales[Quantity],
    "Sales Amount", [Sales Amount],
    "Big Sales Amount", [Big Sales Amount]
)
```